# spark-submit,Client cannot authenticate via:[TOKEN, KERBEROS];

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, kerberos

I set up hadoop cluster with kerberos,but when I run spark-submit,it threw exception.

```
17/10/19 08:46:53 WARN scheduler.TaskSetManager: Lost task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0, 192.168.92.4, executor 1): java.io.IOException: Failed on local exception: java.io.IOException: org.apache.hadoop.security.AccessControlException: Client cannot authenticate via:[TOKEN, KERBEROS]; Host Details : local host is: "slave2/192.168.92.4"; destination host is: "master.hadoop":9000; 
    at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.wrapException(NetUtils.java:776)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1479)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1412)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Invoker.invoke(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:229)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy15.getBlockLocations(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.ClientNamenodeProtocolTranslatorPB.getBlockLocations(ClientNamenodeProtocolTranslatorPB.java:255)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invokeMethod(RetryInvocationHandler.java:191)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invoke(RetryInvocationHandler.java:102)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy16.getBlockLocations(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.callGetBlockLocations(DFSClient.java:1226)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.getLocatedBlocks(DFSClient.java:1213)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.getLocatedBlocks(DFSClient.java:1201)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSInputStream.fetchLocatedBlocksAndGetLastBlockLength(DFSInputStream.java:306)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSInputStream.openInfo(DFSInputStream.java:272)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSInputStream.<init>(DFSInputStream.java:264)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.open(DFSClient.java:1526)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem$3.doCall(DistributedFileSystem.java:304)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem$3.doCall(DistributedFileSystem.java:299)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystemLinkResolver.resolve(FileSystemLinkResolver.java:81)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.open(DistributedFileSystem.java:312)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.open(FileSystem.java:769)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LineRecordReader.<init>(LineRecordReader.java:109)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextInputFormat.getRecordReader(TextInputFormat.java:67)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.HadoopRDD$$anon$1.liftedTree1$1(HadoopRDD.scala:246)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.HadoopRDD$$anon$1.<init>(HadoopRDD.scala:245)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.HadoopRDD.compute(HadoopRDD.scala:203)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.HadoopRDD.compute(HadoopRDD.scala:94)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:287)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:287)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:287)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:87)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:108)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:335)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

I saw kerberos's log,there is only master send authenticate request to KDC when spark app running.Slaves didn't send authenticate request to KDC.

Comment: How did you set up the kerberos? Via kinit or via file attached to spark-submit?

Comment: What Spark execution mode are you trying -- local, standalone, yarn-client, yarn-cluster? Version of Spark? From which distro? Version of Hadoop? From which distro?

Comment: @ThiagoBaldim @SamsonScharfrichter Thank you very much.Exception occurred when I use 'client' as the deploy-mode parameter.I had solved the question.I changed the parameter of the spark-submit command.As follows:`--master yarn --deploy-mode cluster --keytab /etc/krb5.keytab --principal root/bigdataserver03@EXAMPLE.COM`

Answer (score 3):

maybe you can use "**spark-submit --master yarn --deploy-model client --keytab $keytab_file_path --principal $your_principal**"

it seems that this command only works on **yarn-client** mode

Comment: Thank you for the answer, it worked for me! Someone may find this [link](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/spectrum-conductor/2.4.0?topic=applications-submitting-spark-batch-instance-group) useful too.